# How to get/change Spinner Layout Like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to modify the layout/design of Spinner widget like in the image below. but I can't find a way to change the arrow icon on the right side. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/

Comment: Try to set custom background as given above to default Spinner.

Comment: thanks for tutorial friends